# How to add spaces between lines and align elements in the same column in InlineCheckboxes of crispy-form (Django)?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have a form field which is `CheckboxSelectMultiple` and I use `InlineCheckboxes` from `crispy-forms` to make all those check boxes inline. Since I don't have the image of it I will use code snippet as an example.

this is how I want the form looks like in html and I will use `stars` instead of boxes

```
     *name1    *name2    *name3    *name4
     *name5    *name6    *name7    *name8
     *name9    *name10   *name11   *name13
```

What can I do to add more spaces between each line and make it aligns vertically like shown above?

here is my forms.py

```
class AttendanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ['student',]
        widgets = {'student': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()}

    def __init__(self, class_pk, current_user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttendanceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        current_student = Class.objects.get(id=class_pk)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.fields['student'].queryset = current_student.student.order_by('first_name')
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            InlineCheckboxes('student')
        )
```

my current html. (it's not aligned perfectly as shown above!)

```
<form method="POST" class="ml-auto mr-auto">
  {% csrf_token %} 
  <div style="text-align: justify;">{% crispy form form.helper %}</div>
  <button
    type="submit"
    class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
    style="font-size: 15px"
  >
    Check
  </button>
</form>
```

Thanks before hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now all I want to do is to make all elements display inline and add spaces to each line if it has more than one line. So I don't need to use crispy form for that. I remove the all crispy form tags from template and form class then in template all i need to do is:

```
<form method="POST" class="ml-auto mr-auto">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <div class="row mt-2 ml-auto mr-auto">
  {% for form in form.student %}
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <h6 class="ml-2 mt-2" id="info-text">
    {{ form.tag }} {{ form.choice_label }}
   </h6>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
 </div>
 <button
   type="submit"
   class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
   style="font-size: 15px"
 >
   Check
 </button>
</form>
```